# SwiftUI 5: @Observable object updates using no property wrappers, State and Bindable

Tags: swift, swiftui, xcode15

I have the following `SwiftUI 5` code snippet using `XCode 15 beta 4`:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var person: Person = .init(id: UUID(), name: "Stacey")
    //using @State or @Bindable or nothing before 'person' does the same job

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button {
                person.name = "Sarah"
            } label: {
                Text("change name")
            }
            
            Text("Name: \(person.name)")
        }
    }
}

@Observable
class Person: Identifiable {
    var id: UUID
    var name: String
    
    init(id: UUID, name: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
    }
}
```

I wonder what is the difference between using: `@Bindable`, `@State`, or nothing before the `Person` variable in the `ContentView`, because the `person` object updates successfully using any of those 3 choices, and the view can listen to the new change.

Comment: [Discover Observation in SwiftUI](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2023/10149/), this is a good video from WWDC 2023 on the subject

Answer (score 2):

With `@Observable` you can now see changes everywhere as you are experiencing.

`@Bindable` is to make changes , you can use `$someObject.someProperty` and change the property of the object.

`@State` is a source of truth it is for local properties.

Comment: we have now: `State`, `Binding`, `Bindable`, `StateObject`, `ObservedObject` wrappers, I just got confused between binding and bindable as both do the same result

Comment: @JAHelia StateObject and ObservedObject aren’t needed if you are only supporting iOS 17+

Answer (score 0):

> //using @State or @Bindable or nothing before 'person' does the same job

This is because you marked your class `Person` as an `ObservableObject` via applying `@Observable` before the class declaration. Because of this, your instance, `person` will always observe updates regardless of any additional annotation you provide it in your view.

You typically use `@State` when you want to track minor changes to a variable of a non-custom class (like a boolean, string, integer, etc). `@Bindable` can be used in a similar fashion to `@State` except it is more useful to apply it to the initializer of a custom view within your primary view. See the following example.

```
struct PrimaryView: View {
     @State var updateCustomView: Bool = false

     var body: some View {
         CustomView(shouldUpdate: $updateCustomView)
     }
}

struct CustomView: View {
     @Bindable var shouldUpdate: Bool

     var body: some View {
         if shouldUpdate {
            // do stuff
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: this code snippet won't compile as the `Bindable` wrapper won't work with booleans.